# Why is for(int i=0;;i++) considered infinite loop?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

Why is the following loop is considered to be an infinite loop?

```
for(int i=0;;i++)
{
    //
}
```

After `i` reaches its maximum value of **2147483647**, and then when it is incremented,  the program should show an error saying that "Integer number too large" or something like that. And hence, the program should terminate. Even though it will take some time to reach that value, it should certainly not be infinite. So why is it an infinite loop?

Comment: Well technically given infinite memory it would _theoretically_ be infinite... The point is that there is no condition so it shouldn't stop unless something outside the program stops it.

Comment: Pick one language. In C++ it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: On which language exactly?

Comment: Sir, I program in many languages, and so, theoretically, I expect it to behave the same in most of them. But basically, I want an answer for java.

Comment: *"the program should show an error saying that "Integer number too large""* Should? That means you haven't run or own program to verify your assumption?

Comment: @Tom - or perhaps he is telling the designers of the Java programming language that they got it wrong.  (Good luck with that :-) )

Comment: @StephenC Wouldn't the question then be something like "Why does Java allow integer overflow"? :P

Comment: _So why is it an infinite loop?_ Considered by whom??

Comment: @TaW - someone with a finite lifespan :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is for Java. It's been a while since I worked in C# or C++.

No, when an integer is incremented past its max value, it overflows to its min value. There is no exception thrown in this case, so the loop can go on forever, since there's no condition to end the loop (unless there's some break statement inside the loop's body).

Comment: Maybe you have a particular language in mind? Note that the question is tagged in 3, and this is incorrect for at least one of them.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar See my comment. This isn't "correct". At least it wasn't originally.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I had that exact same thought. It seems that many people down vote correct answers on bad questions (happened to me before)

Comment: @juanchopanza I didn't notice the multiple language tags. I have a filter for Java questions, and my answer is for Java.

Comment: @Eran OK, now it is correct AFAIK. Down-vote removed.

Comment: @juanchopanza - But does that make the answer wrong?. I mean a comment like - *which language?*,  would suffice instead of *down-voting* and then reverting back :P

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Of course it made it wrong. It stated something that was incorrect. So yes, down-vote worthy. Now it is OK.

Comment: Overflow of signed integer is undefined behavior in C++.

Comment: Isn't that behavior quite opposite to what is expected of the statement?

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh What statement? `i++`? That expression is not expected to throw any exception.

Comment: Does this occur in all programming languages?

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh I can't answer for all programming languages. If I remember correctly (it has been many years) in Ada you'd get an exception if you exceed the range of the type of the variable you are incrementing, but Ada is more strongly typed than most languages I know.

Comment: @Eran - *"I can't answer for all programming languages."*  Indeed, nobody can!  The instant you do, some clown is going to find ... or invent ... a programming language that contradicts you :-)

Comment: @StephenC That's why I gave a contradicting example myself :) (hopefully I was correct)

Comment: Yes ... the real point here is that *"Does this occur in all programming languages?"* is what we call in the business a "silly question".

Answer (score 2):

When your integer reaches the upper edge, adding 1 will lead it to its lowest possible value.

In fact, this isn't infinite

```
for(int i=0;i>=0;i++);
```

it runs exaclty `Integer.MAX_VALUE` times, because `Integer.MAX_VALUE` + 1 is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, a negative number

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't write any condition, and the language defines it as infinite loop.

Do avoid overflow.

Try these:

C++:

```
#include <limits.h>

for(int i=0;;i++)
{
    //
    if(i == INT_MAX) break;
}
```

Java:

```
for(int i=0;;i++)
{
    //
    if(i == Integer.MAX_VALUE) break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once `i` passes the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it overflows to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. And since you are not defining a condition for your loop, **it will never break**. So in order to break it, either

1. use a `break;` instruction.
2. or set a condition to the loop.

Answer (score 1):

When int reach its maximum value it and increase one more, it will become the minimum instead of give any error.

Answer (score 0):

(For java) this loop is considered an infinite loop:

```
 for(int i=0;;i++)
 {
//
  }
```

Because it doesn't have a condition like below :

```
  for(int i=0;i< number;i++)
  {
//
  }
```

The loop go ahead while this condition `i< number` is `true`: